# Convert Object to Datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas column which contain time data and column datatype is object.

```
time
Aug 23, 2019 16:30:00
Aug 24, 2019 13:50:00
Aug 16, 2019 08:20:00
Aug 18, 2019 09:00:00
```

How to convert the column to Datatime

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(...)`?

Comment: Tried Sir, but getting error.

Comment: Add the things you tried to your question, also add the error. This helps others to understand your problem.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['time'])` where `df` is your dataframe.

Comment: I tried this locally, and it seems to work.

Comment: I am doing this way. anythin wrong. **df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).strftime('%d_%m_%Y')**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For speedup, better to specify the date format,

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format="%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
```

do not do

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).strftime('%d_%m_%Y')
```

as series objects has no attribute 'strftime'

Answer (score 1):

**Convert any string pattern into datetime object using this**

**1.** Write a function which takes in the string object and convertes it into datetime object

**2.** Use .apply() to use the function to all rows of the Series object.

*Check the below code*

```
import datetime

def splitdates(string):
    month, date, year, time = string.split()
    return datetime.date(int(year), month, date[:len(date)-1])

# Assuming time is a Series object
# Do something like this

time.apply(lambda x: splitdates(x))
```